# MYSQL QUERY LEFT JOIN SHOW ALL DATA FROM ONE TABLE

Tags: mysql, left-join, multiple-tables

```
SELECT 
A.CODE,
B.NOTE,
C.NUMBER

FROM (A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.CODE = B.CODE
LEFT JOIN C
ON A.CODE = C.NUMBER
)

WHERE C.ID = B.ID
```

Need to show some results combined from 3 tables, but my results show all data from table B reported also if the data isn't real from table C.

```
Table A.code
1
2
3

Table B.code
1
2
3

Table B.note
pippo 
paperino
pluto

Table C.number
1
```

Ideally there should be one result showing

```
1  1    pippo
```

but in results it is shown:

```
1  1    pippo
1  1    paperino
1  1    pluto
```

How can I get the real data?

Comment: What you need here is `INNER JOIN`s

Comment: What's ID in you `WHERE` condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
A.CODE,
B.NOTE,
C.NUMBER

FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.CODE = B.CODE
INNER JOIN C ON A.CODE = C.NUMBER
```

no need for WHERE cluse

Answer (score 1):

You need INNER JOIN

```
SELECT 
A.CODE,
B.NOTE,
C.NUMBER

FROM C
INNER JOIN B on C.Number=B.Code
INNER JOIN A on B.Code=A.Code
```

Answer (score 0):

LEFT JOIN will take all results from the table mentioned on the left side. Try JOIN instead which is an INNER JOIN afaik