# Get all the data from a table and sometimes relate that table with another

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

My question is: **Can I do this?**
I try many things, some of them are:

- [Search 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787084/mysql-query-left-join-show-all-data-from-one-table)
- [Search 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965565/data-from-two-tables-and-one-show)
- [Search 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640428/joining-two-similar-tables-in-mysql)
- [Search 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611818/how-can-i-select-all-the-data-from-a-table-with-condition)

I need all the info form **Table A**, and sometimes I need to join this table with **Table B**. My problem is that when I join both tables, if an specific parameter in **Table A** is not in **Table B** just give me the records when the `specific parameter are`, but I want all the records.

**Table A**

```
|--------------------------------|
|           Table A              |
|-------------------|------------|
| id_table_A | name | id_table_B |
|------------|------|------------|
|   1        | Joe  |  1         |
|------------|------|------------|
|   2        | Ben  |            |
|------------|------|------------|
|   3        | Lya  |            |
|------------|------|------------|
|   4        | luis |  2         |
|------------|------|------------|
```

**Table B**

```
|----------------------|
|      Table B         |
|----------------------|
| id_table_B | Elements|
|------------|---------|
|   1        |    Car  | 
|------------|---------|
|   2        |    Byke | 
|------------|---------|
|   3        |    Moto | 
|------------|---------|
```

What I want to show in my **View** is this:

```
|------------|------|------------|
| id_table_A | name | Elements   |
|------------|------|------------|
|   1        | Joe  |  Car       |
|------------|------|------------|
|   2        | Ben  |            |
|------------|------|------------|
|   3        | Lya  |            |
|------------|------|------------|
|   4        | luis |  Byke      |
|------------|------|------------|
```

**My model**
In my model this is what I tried:

```
"SELECT * FROM table_A, table_B where table_A.id_table_B = table_B.id_table_B"
```

But this query only show me data **1 and 4**.
This can be done or not?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: With `LEFT JOIN` of course

Comment: Does it not work if you do `SELECT * FROM table_A` and just `LEFT JOIN` table B?

Comment: @Giedrius When I do `Select * from table_A left join table B` that give me a syntax error

Comment: `My question is: Can I do this?` Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use left join

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_A
left join table_B on table_A.id_table_B = table_B.id_table_B
```

Left join is used when the keys between tables may not always match. In this case, the left join retrieves the correct match where it's possible and the values become `NULL` when not possible.

[SQL LEFT JOIN Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

Comment: Good answer, I just wish you explained _why_ more, or at least linked to documentation instead of just "Just do this >>code paste<<"

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton    answer  updated  with a simple but i hop clear  explanation

Answer (score 0):

You need an explicit `LEFT JOIN` as opposed to the implicit `INNER JOIN` that is used when you simply list the tables like that. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp